# How do you specify $? options in an rpm file

Tags: linux, rpmbuild

I'm trying to build freetds but want it to include the static libraries in freetds-devel.  It looks like it takes an option `_with_static` but it's unclear to specify it.  Here's a section of the RPM file:

```
%build
%configure \
        --disable-dependency-tracking \
        --disable-rpath \
        %{!?_with_static: --disable-static} \
        --with-tdsver="4.2" \
        --with-unixodbc="%{_prefix}" \
        --enable-msdblib \
        --enable-sybase-compat \
        --with-gnutls
```

So short of altering the spec file to have just the options I want how do I specify `_with_static` when I run `rpmbuild`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `--with static` to `rpmbuild`.